# Zero values based on another cells content

Tags: vba

I am after a bit of code please.

I would like columns AB, AD, AF, AL, AN, AP to all revert to 0 if column Q is closed.  This is for each row.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do some research about the `Worksheet_Change` event and see if that fit's your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
Public Sub SetZeroForClosed()
Dim TRange As Range
   Set TRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   For i = 1 To TRange.Rows.Count
 If VBA.LCase(VBA.Trim(TRange.Cells(i, 17).Value)) = VBA.LCase("Closed") Then
    TRange.Cells(i, 28).Value = 0
    TRange.Cells(i, 30).Value = 0
    TRange.Cells(i, 32).Value = 0
    TRange.Cells(i, 38).Value = 0
    TRange.Cells(i, 40).Value = 0
    TRange.Cells(i, 42).Value = 0
 End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: use this vba code and put into macro , do you have idea, right how to run this code and run it.

Comment: send me snap of that error, as well the snap of code

Comment: I have updated the code , Please take latest code from above

Comment: The code works fine thanks..  Maybe a stupid question but how do i make it run all the time...

Comment: call  that function code into worksheet_change event.

Comment: please dont forget to rate this question helpfull or answered

Comment: Currently only 60 but that will grow.

Comment: call that function code into worksheet_change event. what do you mean by this..  I am new to VBA

Comment: Sorted it...  Thanks :)